# Cacheing inline code chunk in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Does anyone know if and how it is possible to chache inline code chunks in knitr/rmarkdown?

This was my starting point, but does not work:

````
---
title: "Test of inline chunk caching"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE)
```

## Test of inline chunk caching

Test test `r Sys.sleep(10)` test test
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of a way to cache inline code. But you can create a chunk of code that houses all of the same variables and computations you will expand on in the text and in-line code.

Just set that block to suppress the visibility of the code, warnings and output then set `cache=TRUE`. It basically runs and hides the results. Then you have the data saved into a variable sublimely. You can call it up at any time by inserting the variable into in-line code. And it will remain available in following chunks.

[This link takes you to a cheat sheet with all of the arguments for chunks on the second page.](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf)

Comment: Thank's. So I will do it that way and cache the "between-line" chunk.